# How to get borough from UK postcode using CoreLocation in swift?

Tags: swift, core-location

Does anyone know if I can get the borough from a UK post code using CoreLocation framework? In the function listed below, the borough is not returned. It should return Tower Hamlets.

```
  func getLocationFrom(postalCode : String){
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(postalCode) {
        (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        let placemark = placemarks?[0] 
             print("placemark.addressDictionary are \(placemark.addressDictionary)") //does not print Canary Wharf  
    }
}

print(getLocationFrom(postalCode:"E14 9LR")) //does not print Tower Hamlets, it prints London, which is the city, not the borough..
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the locality from a postcode you just have to subscript `placemarks` array and then access the property `locality` for the element at the indexPath you want. My mistake was that I was trying to access another property on the `placemarks` array, namely `addressDictionary` which was not producing the expected result.

```
 func getLocationFrom(postalCode: String, callback: @escaping(_ locality: String?) -> Void){


    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(postalCode) {
        (placemarks, error) -> Void in

       callback(placemarks?[0].locality)

    }
```

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question but please don't just post code. Explain what was wrong with the original code and explain how this answer solves the issue.

Comment: It turns out that I was wrong, I still don't get the borough for the post code input. Please see my revised question. Instead I get the city..